# Swift Package Manager - binaryTarget with .zip file fails to validate

Tags: swift-package-manager

I tried different approaches to add a binaryTarget to a Swift package - 2 of them worked out fine (`Target1` and `Target2` in the example), but third approach (`Target3`) that should also work according to documentation does not validate: `unsupported extension for binary target 'Target3'; valid extensions are: xcframework`

For not bloating the repo too much with every binary release I would prefer the zip approach here... - Anyone got it working with a `binaryTarget` and a `.zip` file in `path:` added to the Package repository, or any hints what I'm doing wrong here?
(Xcode 12.4, `t3.zip` containing only the `.xcframework` at root level)

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "StackoverflowExamplePackage",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v9)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Lib1",
            targets: ["Target1"]),
        .library(
            name: "Lib2",
            targets: ["Target2", "Target3"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "Target1",
            url: "https://myurl.example.com/t1-xcframework.zip",
            checksum: "777ddd6381e2201b7eb778b72f373f77e1190fd9dc9503f703e37c86d3b89674"
        ),
        .binaryTarget(name: "Target2", path: "./Binaries/t2.xcframework"),
        .binaryTarget(name: "Target3", path: "./Binaries/t3.zip"),
    ]
)
```

[image: Package Example]
[image: Apple Documentation]

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am wondering the same.

Comment: not really, finally went with the "Target1" approach from my example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Zip` archive support for local binary targets in `SPM` [was merged](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/3746) last year in October and has been finally released along with `Xcode 13.3`.